# add paramters to jsonp callback function in ExpressJS and NodeJS

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, jsonp

I am using `$.ajax` for jsonp request to ExpressJS handler which returns:

```
res.jsonp({status: "200", message: "Finished"})
```

This works great.

I would like my callback function in the success function of JQuery ajax to be invoked with these parameters:

```
callback(status, message)
```

But as you can see I can return on JSON data from [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.jsonp)

P.S. is checking the status in the JQuery success function is the corrent way, i.e.:

```
$.ajax({
   ///.....
   success: function(resp){
      if(resp && resp.status === '200'){
         // success
      }
      else {// error
      }
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. From the Express documentation:
   http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.jsonp
   It's better to use `res.status(200).jsonp({ message : "Finished" })`.
   By default, the JSONP callback name is simply `callback`. Override this with the `jsonp callback name` setting.
2. Success callback prototype is `Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )`.
   So to check response status you might do the following:

   ```
   $.ajax({
       // ...
       success : function(data, status, xhr) {
           if (xhr.status === 200) {
               // ...
           }
       }
   });
   ```